# Custom layer/overlay in google maps

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to create custom layers/overlays in google maps?

As an example, would it be possible to have one layer with polygons, another with circles, and a third with markers? and then hide/show these layers individually?

I tried looking at the documentation, but the layers seems to only be a fixed set of predefined layers. And overlays seems to only support image overlays.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there exists a better way to do this, but I've found a workaround to a similar problem. My example utilizes markers and polylines, but it should be easy to extend the functionality to circles and polygons too.

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ferian/EeLQn/)

Basically it works like this:

1. Initialize the map.
2. User selects an option what he would like to see on the map.
3. Click triggers a method (see HTML part of the fiddle) in the map object that first clears the map and then pushes new overlays on map.

The data that is currently shown on map is stored in arrays, and the map clearing method simply goes through these arrays and checks if there exists any content on map, and removes them if does.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: this does not help, its just clearing all and then redrawing.. not truly layers.